# ionic check a value on a json array and then apply a css class

Tags: html, css, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I'm studying the ionic framework, and I'm making a simple app to display some json data, I had no problems applying a different style for text strings in my ionic list (story.user)but now I would change the background color for range of values for example:

`"less than 2"` `"between 2 and 5"` `"greater than 5"` for the `"story.val"`

But i have no idea how to do ... can anyone help me?

I don't find many documentation about inline conditional expression....

This is the simple code succesful with strings, html and css:

***HTML:***

```
<ion-content>
    <div class="list">
        <div class="item" ng-repeat="story in stories">
            {{story.val}} - {{story.place}} - {{story.end}}
            <p ng-class="{ 'user1': 'status-okay', 'user2': 'status-medium', 'user3' : 'status-risk'}[story.user]">{{story.user}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

***CSS:***

```
.status-okay {
    background-color: green;
}

.status-medium {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.status-risk {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
 <p ng-class="{ 'user1': 'status-okay', 'user2': 'status-medium', 'user3' : 'status-risk'}[story.user]">{{story.user}}</p>
```

to

```
<p ng-class="{'status-okay': story.val<2, 
               'status-medium': (story.val>=2 && story.val<=5), 
               'status-risk': story.val>5} ">
 {{story.user}}
</p>
```

[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) you can read more about ngClass

Answer (score 0):

You can write expressions for ionic (angular) to evaluate within `ng-class`:

```
ng-class="{story.val < 2: 'class-a', story.val > 2 && story.val < 5: 'class-b', story.val > 5: 'class-c'}"
```

Replace `class-a`, `class-b`, and `class-c` with the class names you wish to use